# passing next/prev cell data between UITableViewController and UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, delegates, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController with a segue to a UIViewController that display the cell's data. In the UIViewController i want to place two buttons to get the next cell and the previous cell (without the need to navigate back to the UITableViewController and selecting a new cell).
I created a delegate that is invoked when one of the buttons is clicked and send the current object as a parameter.
I have two questions:

1. can I get the indexPath from the object in the UITableViewController method?
2. Is there a function that will cause the segue to invoke with the new indexPath?

Comment: Why not pass the data for the 3 cells you're interested in to 3 properties in that controller (or an array if you'd rather). You don't really need to use a delegate for what you're doing.

Comment: my UITableViewController holds many cells and in the UIViewController i want to browse, i.e. from the UITableViewController i started by clicking row #6 i want to be able to browse all the way to 1 or to n

Comment: So you don't just want the next and previous cell data? Is that right? You want to be able to look at any cells' data from the UIViewController?

Comment: @rdelmar, Yes & No, i would like to be able to see all cells but from the current display i'd like to only see my previous or next cell, I don't wish that the UIViewController will know the entire array and manage by itself the order/browsing since the "manager" is the UITableViewController

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. My first comment was a way to see the current, previous, and next cell values, but you said you wanted to go from 1 to n. Now you say you only want the 3. You're talking in circles.

Comment: In order to get from x to n you'll have to go one by one through all the cells until you reach n. so i do want to be able to browse through all my cells from 1 to n. saying that i want to have a good OOD that means the UIViewController is only a "displayer" of a given cell, thus it should get its data from the UITableViewController. this behavior is achievable using a delegate that will return the next cell to display, i hope i managed to explain myself better this time

Comment: I've updated my answer to what I think you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can do what you want with a delegate method. Delegate methods can return values just like any other method, so you could do something like this. In this example, I just have a label in ViewController that displays the data from the selected row of the table view. Here is the code for ViewController:

```
@protocol DetailDelegate <NSObject>
-(NSString *)valueForNextOrPreviousCell:(NSInteger) nextOrPrevious;
@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak,nonatomic) id <DetailDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic) NSInteger selectedRow;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSString *dataToDisplay;
@end


@interface ViewController ()
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.label.text = self.dataToDisplay;
}

-(IBAction)nextOrPreviousClicked:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

    if ([sender.title isEqualToString:@"Next"]) {
        self.selectedRow += 1;
    }else{
        self.selectedRow -= 1;
    }

    NSString *data = [self.delegate valueForNextOrPreviousCell:self.selectedRow];
    self.label.text = data;
}
```

Then in the prepareForSegue method in TableController and in the implementation of the delegate method, I have this:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    NSInteger row = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row;
    ViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
    vc.delegate = self;
    vc. selectedRow = row;
    vc.dataToDisplay = self.theData[row];
}


-(NSString *)valueForNextOrPreviousCell:(NSInteger)nextOrPrevious {
    if (nextOrPrevious < 0) nextOrPrevious = 0;
    if (nextOrPrevious >= self.theData.count -1) nextOrPrevious = self.theData.count - 1;
    return self.theData[nextOrPrevious];
}
```